# Visual-Studio, existing way to create definition for all?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

When creating matching header and source files in Visual-Studio, it's possible to right click on any method and have visual-studio generate the definition (in source) for you.
[image]

Perhaps my coding-style is unusual, however I will normally write out several-classes worth of declarations, then create all the definitions afterwards.

I don't mind manually adding all the definitions, however given this feature exists (and I make great use of it), is anyone aware if VS can natively, or with a plugin, effectively "batch create" definitions for all declarations in a header? There seems to be little I can find by way of google on this topic.

Comment: This would be very useful, and I believe that it wouldn't be all that hard to implement considering that the functionality already exists, it would just need to be automated.

Answer (score 5):

Just select all methods beforehand then generate definition like you would for a single method.

Comment: Yes:
Highlight each declaration in your .h file.
Right click -> Quick Actions and Refactorings... -> Create Declaration / Definition

The stubs should then be in the associated .cpp file.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I just get "no quick actions available here" with multiple declarations selected. In fact it does that even if I put the cursor on one method declaration and press Ctrl+. It only works if I actually hover the mouse, wait for the tooltip to come up, and _then_ press Ctrl+. 

Answer (score 0):

Among other answers, I would like to add something. After selecting all function declarations you want to create a definition for, you have you hover your mouse over the side near the line numbers and click the screwdriver there, selecting "Create Declaration / Definition". If you click the screwdriver in the text edit area, it sometimes only shows the option to create a definition for a specific function.

[image: Correct button to click]